# Why Apache Spark has added cache() method even though we can achieve the same functionality by calling persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

Tags: apache-spark, caching, persist

Why spark added cache() method in its library i.e. rdd.py even though it internally calls self.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) as stated below:

```
def cache(self):
    """
    Persist this RDD with the default storage level (C{MEMORY_ONLY}).
    """
    self.is_cached = True
    self.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    return self
```

Comment: I would recommend to ask the guys who developed it. This is not a programming question per se. :) You should also be able to find something in their docs / manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache` is a convenience method to cache a Dataframe. `Persist` is an advanced method which can take storage level as parameter and persist the dataframe accordingly.

The default storage level for `cache` and `persist` are same and as you mentioned duplicated. You can use either. 
In Scala implementation `cache` calls `persist` `def cache(): this.type = persist()`. This tells me that `persist` is the real implementation and `cache` is sugar syntax.